# D3 bar chart not working properly with all negative and positive values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to create bar chart with the help of d3 with positive and negative values. Chart working fine with combination of positive and negative values but if I pass only negative or positive values the X-axis is not coming at proper place. Thanks

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mohit_Agrawal/fjuak9bo/7/)

[BarChart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmEyG.png)

```
//var data = [["Since Mar 10, 2015",150], ["1 year",-100], ["3 year",6.9], ["Since Mar 10, 2010",100]];

var data = [["Since Mar 10, 2015",-100], ["1 year",-10]];

d3.select("#example")
.datum(data)
.call(columnChart()
  .width(320)
  .height(240)
  .x(function(d, i) { return d[0]; })
  .y(function(d, i) { return d[1]; }));

function columnChart() {
  var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 50},
  width = 20,
  height = 20,
  xRoundBands = 0.6,
  xValue = function(d) { return d[0]; },
  yValue = function(d) { return d[1]; },
  xScale = d3.scale.ordinal(),
  yScale = d3.scale.linear(),
  yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left"),
  xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale);
  var isNegative = false;    

 function chart(selection) {
   selection.each(function(data) {

   // Convert data to standard representation greedily;
   // this is needed for nondeterministic accessors.
  for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
     if(data[i][1] < 0){
       isNegative = true;
    }
  }  

  data = data.map(function(d, i) {
    return [xValue.call(data, d, i), yValue.call(data, d, i)];
  });

  // Update the x-scale.
  xScale
      .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d[0];} ))
      .rangeRoundBands([0, width - margin.left - margin.right], xRoundBands);

  // Update the y-scale.
  if( data.length < 2 ){
     if( data.map(function(d) { return d[1];} ) < 0){
         yScale
          .domain([data.map(function(d) { return d[1];} ), 0])
          .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0])
          .nice();         
     }else{
         yScale
          .domain([0, data.map(function(d) { return d[1];} )])
          .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0])
          .nice();
     }
  }else{
      yScale
          .domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d[1];} )))
          .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0])
          .nice();
  }

    // Select the svg element, if it exists.
  var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data]);

  // Otherwise, create the skeletal chart.
  var gEnter = svg.enter().append("svg").append("g");

  gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "y axis");
  gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "x axis");
  gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "x axis zero");

  // Update the outer dimensions.
  svg .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  // Update the inner dimensions.
  var g = svg.select("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Update the y-axis.
     g.select(".y.axis")
        .call(yAxis.tickSize(0).ticks(5))
        .selectAll("g")
        .selectAll("text")
        .text(function(d){
            return d+"%";
        });

    g.append("g")
        .selectAll("line.line")
        .data(yScale.ticks(5))
        .enter()
        .append("line")
         .attr(
            {
                "class":"line grid tick",
                "x1" : 0,
                "x2" : ( width - 60 ),
                "y1" : function(d){ return yScale(d);},
                "y2" : function(d){ return yScale(d);},
            });
    gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "bars");

    // Update the bars.
    var bar = g.select(".bars")
    .selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data);

    bar.enter().append("rect");
    bar.exit().remove();
    bar .attr("class", function(d, i) { return d[1] < 0 ? "bar negative" :   "bar positive"; })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return X(d); })
      .attr("y", function(d, i) { return d[1] < 0 ? Y0() : Y(d); })
      .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
      .attr("height", function(d, i) { return Math.abs( Y(d) - Y0() ); });

  // x axis at the bottom of the chart
  if( isNegative === true ){
    var xScaleHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom+12;
  }else{
    var xScaleHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 }        
  g.select(".x.axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + ( xScaleHeight ) + ")")
    .call(xAxis.orient("bottom"))
    .selectAll("text")
    .call(wrap, xScale.rangeBand());

  // zero line
  g.select(".x.axis.zero")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + Y0() + ")")
    .attr("class", "zero axis")
    .call(xAxis.tickFormat("").tickSize(0));


   // Update the text in bars.
   var bar1 = svg.select(".bars").selectAll("text").data(data);

   bar1 .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append("text")
       .attr("class", "text")
       .text(function(d) { return d[1]+"%"; })
       .attr("x", function(d) { return X(d); })
       .attr("y", function(d, i) { return d[1] < 0 ? Math.abs(Y(d)+10) : Y(d)-2; });
});
```

}

```
  // Custom function for text wrap
   function wrap(text, width) {
     text.each(function() {
     var text = d3.select(this),
     words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
     word,
     line = [],
     lineNumber = 0,
     lineHeight = 1, // ems
     y = text.attr("y"),
     dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
     tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
   while (word = words.pop()) {
   line.push(word);
   tspan.text(line.join(" "));
   if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > 55) {
     line.pop();
     tspan.text(line.join(" "));
     line = [word];
     tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
   }
 }
```

});
 }

```
 // The x-accessor for the path generator; xScale ∘ xValue.
  function X(d) {
  return xScale(d[0]);
 }

 function Y0() {
  return yScale(0);
 }

 // The x-accessor for the path generator; yScale ∘ yValue.
 function Y(d) {
  return yScale(d[1]);
 }

 chart.margin = function(_) {
  if (!arguments.length) return margin;
   margin = _;
   return chart;
  };

 chart.width = function(_) {
   if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = _;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.height = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
     height = _;
     return chart;
   };

  chart.x = function(_) {
   if (!arguments.length) return xValue;
    xValue = _;
    return chart;
   };

   chart.y = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return yValue;
      yValue = _;
      return chart;
    };

   return chart;
}
```

Comment: it is working fine, where do you think it should combine??

Comment: Hey @ozil Please tried with all positive values like " var data = [["Since Mar 10, 2015",100], ["1 year",200]]; " the X-axis will disappear.

Comment: Do you always want to scale the Y axis? What about just doing http://jsfiddle.net/fjuak9bo/8/ ?

Comment: Actually I need the zero axis dynamic if there is only positive value it has to shifted to bottom and in negative value it has shifted at top. So the graph use all area and also looks clean. And the values come from the service its comes under ( +150 To -100 ) range.

Comment: `range` should be between `0-100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified your example slightly http://jsfiddle.net/fjuak9bo/9/ which I believe provides the solution you want.

The important part is to set your `domain` on the `yscale` appropriately. Here I'm detecting if all values are +ve or -ve, and setting the domain between -100-0 or 0-100.

```
yScale.domain([-100, 100])
          .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0])
          .nice();         

    if(min > 0) { 
        // All positive
        yScale.domain([0, 100]);
    } else if(max < 0) {
        // All negative
        yScale.domain([-100, 0]);   
    }
```

You could if you needed extend the min/max on the domain if you're values exceed +- 100%.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @lan but if I pass " data = [["Since Mar 10, 2015",-100], ["1 year",150]] " the bar goes out of the graph scale and I also need the zero axis dynamic.

Comment: @MohitAgrawal : OK - is this working fine? Or is there some additional stuff that I need to answer? If this does what you're after or explains enough to let you finish what you needed please feel free to accept this as the answer. Otherwise if you elaborate a little I can update/add a comment to explain.